# Create XML text nodes in ColdFusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

In ColdFusion's XML DOM abstraction, there is a function to create an element, and you can set the text content of an element through a property. But I can't see how to create a snippet like this:

```
<a>some<b>text</b>here</a>
```

I would expect to create text nodes containing the strings, but I don't know how to create a text node. There doesn't seem to be a factory function for that. Is this possible using pure ColdFusion, or do I need to use Java?

Comment: Have you tried using cdata? `<cfset xmlObj.root.childName.xmlText = '<![CDATA[<a>some<b>text</b>here</a>]]>'>`. I have never used ColdFusion's XML DOM abstraction so this is just a guess.

Comment: `<a>` and `<b>` should be elements containing text; I'm not trying to insert the escaped literal string "<a>".

Comment: So 'a' and 'b' are xml elements, and not Anchor and Bold as part of HTML string you want insert?

Comment: Right. There is no HTML here.

Comment: Then I think your problem is in your nesting. You cant have a="some", a.b="test", and then a="here" afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML document object actually uses text nodes, but doesn't show it in the dump. Try this:

```
a = xmlParse("<a>some<b>text</b>here</a>");
writeDump(a.xmlRoot.xmlNodes);
```

[image: writeDump(a.xmlRoot.xmlNodes)]

The **xmlNodes** array is well documented: [The XML document object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec133ba-7fd9.html)

AFAIK there is no possibility to create a **new text node** in ColdFusion. But you can always find an **existing text node** in the document, **duplicate** it, replace its **xmlValue** and insert it in any **xmlNodes** array.

Comment: That looks like a pain, but if that's the only way to do it, then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `<cfsavecontent>` tag to have complete control over the XML structure. It allows you to do something like this:

```
<cfset somevariable = "some dynamic value">

<cfsavecontent variable="myXML">
    <cfoutput>
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <a>some<b>text</b>here</a>
        <c>#somevariable#</c>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfdump var="#myXML#">
```

Then your XML structure is stored in the `myXML` variable.

[Documentation for the cfsavecontent tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d57.html).

In `cfscript` it would look something like this:

```
<cfscript>
    somevariable = "some dynamic value";

    savecontent variable="myXML" { WriteOutput("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><a>some<b>text</b>here</a><c>#somevariable#</c>"); }
    writeDump(myXML);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: The downside here is that you have to a) use tag syntax, which we're trying to move away from and b) manually escape everything. Your example has an error: `<c>#somevariable#</c>` should be `<c>#XmlFormat(somevariable)#</c>`.

Comment: @ThomSmith You don't have to use tag syntax. I included a `cfscript` example. Yes you should wrap the `XmlFormat(somevariable)` it just depends on what the value is intended to be. I just added that as an example so you could see that ColdFusion variables could also be used in the output generation.

Answer (score 0):

This is closest I can get for you, asking for XML and not an array.

```
<cfxml variable="xmlapiData">
    <a b="text">some here</a>
</cfxml>
<cfdump var="#xmlapiData#">
```

will produce:

[image]

That is of course tag based.